# Can images have the same name?

Tags: seo, images, filenames

Will it harm SEO to have images with the same name?

In the process of bulk optimizing images for the web and im wondering how the images should be renamed, is it ok to have imagename-1, imagename-2 or should they be more specific?

Comment: Are those names descriptive of what is in the image?    Are you worried more about image search rankings or web search rankings?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same name for same kind of picture. But use specific name will help a little for SEO, but it also mean more work to do. Determined by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are more specific, Google will understand better what is your image. 
Try to use keywords and variations.
It would help.